# Cordova app suddenly not working correctly anymore

Tags: android, cordova, webview

since a few days ago i believe (mid march '15), my previously built apps with phonegap and/or cordova don't work properly anymore and this without updating anything. The Webview app seems to be the culprit since I load .html files as views. Webview is version 40 (1808730). Android 5.0.2 and 5.1.
Anyone with the same issue? Is there a fix somewhere?

Edit: it seems that Android >= 5.0.2 breaks my app. I could check on 5.0.1 and they still work ok. Any idea what changed? The apps are compiled with Cordova 4.3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix it but I did a bunch of things to finally get it to work again and honestly not sure which step actually fixed it.. Here's what I did. I uninstalled all of my plugins then forced the android platform update

```
cordova platform update android@3.7.1
```

then re added the plugins then compiled. Then uninstalled and reinstalled my plugins then recompiled. That fixed the display issues (Also I did uninstall and reinstall my android SDK's ...).

Answer (score 2):

I am also seeing changes. After Android Web View was updated to v.40 on 3/30/2015, my Cordova (v.4.3.0) app that displays Google Maps started missing tiles when I pan the map. Missing tiles appear as black squares and sometimes they reappear after a couple of seconds sometimes they don't.

To make sure I am not imagining this, I uninstalled the WebView update - the problem disappeared. I reinstalled the update - the problem appeared again.

I was not able to find the cure so far.